# App crashes if i run app without any breakpoints,but when i run using breakpoints it runs fine in ios.How to check issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

When i run my app using breakpoint it runs fine and gives no error,but when i remove breakpoint and rut,it crashes.And it doesn't crash on simulator and crashes on device.So in this case how to find error?

Comment: enable zombies and check once

Comment: How to enable zombies?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode

Comment: @sp309 or you can try reset your simulator once.

Comment: No still this problem happens@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Can you show related codes ?

Comment: You can check the device logs.. Just run the app on device and then xcode-window - device..Select your device and  Try to find what is going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

It's a thread issue .. try to

```
runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlockingUpload(^{


    //Do stuff
      });

void runOnMainQueueWithoutDeadlockingUpload(void (^block)(void))
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        block();
    }
    else
    {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
    }
}
```

for heavy task you doing while starting the app.

Comment: i have checked multiple times.it crashes when running directly but when i use breakpoint it doesn't crash.

Comment: @VishalSonawane because when puts breakpoint the task in the background thread finishes and hence it is not crashing on the other hand when he runs in the real time background which may be giving some data is not finished yet. hence crashes..

Comment: @vivek unsubscribe failed with error: (Error Domain=OTSessionErrorDomain Code=1112 "(null)")

Comment: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Constants/OTSessionErrorCode.html     check this out for error code 1112 and see what's missing in your code

Comment: i already visited this link.but how can i get solution form that?

Answer (score 0):

**it is very simple when u put break point it is not crash and without breakpoint it is crash so what code u are execute put some delay then it will resolve**

```
 double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

// Add Your code here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something happening wrong in async thread and in special cases other thread do work slowly! You need check these cases.